# Entity Framework, Function Import with Return Type: None.. returns int?

Tags: entity-framework, return-type

I've added a Stored Procedure to my Store, which creates a Function Import in my Model, and I've set the Return Type to None, as the Stored Procedure merely does an Insert or Update.

Yet, the generated ObjectContext method returns an int, as opposed to void. When I execute this method, and it works, this value is -1.

What's going on here?

**[EDIT]**

the SPROC is simple and looks like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
UPDATE Notes SET vchType = @Type, iPriority=5 WHERE iNoteNumber = @NoteID
```

Nothing *should* be returned, and *if* I execute into a variable, I'd think it'd be zero, like in SSMS:

```
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [CNRD].[UpdateNoteType]
            @NoteID = 12345,
            @Type = N'REGULAR'

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
    ------------------------------------------
    [ Return Value ]
    0
```

Here's how it's mapped:

[image: SPROC mapping]
[image: function import]
[image: generated method]

Comment: could you show the code, and perhaps a screenshot of how you imported the function?

Comment: I'll snag some screenshots and edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non query method , see remarks here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Comment: This has nothing to do with EntityFramework. How should OP should use this method?

Comment: The link explains and I quote  " For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."  Entity framework is just returning the value it got from the SP. so I agree it has jack to do with EF.   EF was asked to call an SP and the SP most likely returned -1   seems  relevant to me when you ask "When I execute this method, and it works, this value is -1."  Just trying to help explain.

Comment: ok. I thought that was unclear in your answer. In EF when you import an SP, you deside what it should return. if you choose `None` the wrapper EF makes around the SP, will return `void` regardless of what is actually returned from the SP.

Comment: that im not sure about Jens, so still a valid question. I just felt that the standard SQL non query command result was the most likely source of your value.  I call such commands directly and not via EF.